# adjusting a picture size and pasting it to selected range in otherworkbook

Tags: image, vba, excel, copy-paste

This might to be too easy to ask but i am a beginner.

I want to be able to copy ranges from a worksheet and paste it to another worksheet in adjusted size which i should pick and paste it to selected range area in the otherworksheet.

When i do this by using a macro, i can paste it and adjust its size manually.When i try to use this recoreded macro again, it does not paste it to the range that i have selected and its size is not like its original nor like my adjusted size.

How can i specify the size and the ranges the paste?

Comment: Ranges of data or images?

Comment: Well i have made a Image of the ranges. I can also leave as range if you suggest me to do so though.

Answer (score 1):

If you paste image, you can use .width, .height, .top, .left to position it and to set it width and height. Also if you wana to fit in certain range, you can specify it by .width, .height, .top, .left atributes of that range, or even cells. Need further example? It seems too clear to me :(

edit: Try something like this

```
Sub copyPic()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With targetSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).CopyPicture
        .Paste
        Selection.Name = "pastedPic"

        With .Shapes("pastedPic")
            .Top = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Top
            .Left = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Left
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 50

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

You can use something like

```
.range("A1:B10")
```

instead of my reference, but try to understand it, its much easier to read. It tells you that you wana range which have two corners cells which are specified by row and column number (in this order). Or selection can even be .range(.cells(1,"A"),.cells(3,"C")) but numbers are number... and eventualy if you need to increment range columns or numbers... its much better aproach

So for your need it will be

```
Sub copyPic()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With targetSheet
        .Range("A1:B10") .CopyPicture
        .Paste
        Selection.Name = "pastedPic"

        With .Shapes("pastedPic")
            .Top = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Top
            .Left = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Left
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 50

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

If you wana to paste it to another workbook, try something like this

```
Sub copyPic()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim targetWB as excel.workbook
    set targetWB = workbooks.open("pathToYourWorkbook") 
    With targetSheet
        .Range("A1:B10") .CopyPicture
        targetWb.sheets("sheetName").Paste
        Selection.Name = "pastedPic"

        With .Shapes("pastedPic")
            .Top = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Top
            .Left = targetSheet.Cells(5, 5).Left
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 50

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there way to select the specific cells with letters like A1:C30 which sais i copy that range ?  i dont get this layout .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).CopyPicture

Comment: yeah i just realised that so copying is fine but i really found it harder since i use columns like CD,CC etc, hard to find which number that it correspounds to :) so how do i also select the range that i paste to ? can i just select the range  so my Image directly fits to that range ?

Comment: I dont think so. You paste image somewhere and then set its top and left (which will set its position) and then set width and height (which will be its size). And you can use top, left, width, height atributes of cells where you wana past picture

Comment: bytheway when i put the .range it gives an error with red when i try to copy

Comment: when you use .range with dot, you need to specify to which sheet range belongs to. Thats why i use with + end with block. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: now ist working, thanks a lot for the help! i Need to ask you one more Thing if you have time too. I want to copy ranges between A1: P40 but i want to exlucede  A7:F40. Is that possible?

Comment: if you just wana to exclude number or text or whatever you have in A7:F40 then just change its color to same color as cell background and after copy change it back. I dont think you can copy and paste cell with excluded range. How it will look like? Picture with hole? :p

Comment: yeah haha i thought having a Picture like a lego haha. but seriously i though so

Comment: i Need to have a blank area there because i Need a text box area in that part which i exclude

Comment: You need textbox above copied picture, or to not copy from source? You can set his .visible = false before copy and .visible = true after copy if you dont vana to copy him or paste him above picture with .ZOrderPosition

Comment: thank you for the info ! i got one last question to you. In your code i can paste the selected range to the same worksheet. what if i want to paste it to Workbook called "Masterworkbook" and the sheet of it called "Page1". how do i make it pasted to this file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104372/discussion-between-lubos-suk-and-yigit-tanverdi).